# appending data to a CSV file and removing list brackets?

Tags: python, csv, class, methods

I built a web scraping class and am now trying to write the average costs & other values to a csv file with this method--

```
def avg_data_to_csv(self):
    avg_data = self.avg_data
    df = pd.DataFrame(avg_data, columns=['Location', 'Average Price', 'Average Price per SQFT'])
    csv = df.to_csv('AVG_DATA.csv', index=False)
    return csv
```

I then wrote another method to add the updated average values to the same csv file in a new row each time I run the program--

```
def add_to_avg_csv(self):
    new_data = self.avg_data
    with open('AVG_DATA.csv', 'a') as obj:
        writer_object = csv.DictWriter(obj, fieldnames=self.avg_data)
        writer_object.writerow(new_data)
        obj.close()
```

However, when I test this, my csv file looks like this-

[csv file after two runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LykT7.png)

I can't figure out how to add the data without the list brackets. How would I go about removing the list brackets when I add the new data to the file?

Comment: 1) What is structure of `self.avg_data`? 2) `with open('AVG_DATA.csv', 'a') as obj` is a context manager that will close `obj` automatically, you don't need `obj.close()`. 3) I doubt that you want to do this `fieldnames=self.avg_data` as `fieldnames` should point at a list/tuple of  field names not a dataset. 4) Why `new_data = self.avg_data` and then `writer_object.writerow(new_data)`? **ADD answers to above as update to your question**.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using writerow() the easiest way would be  for your function avg_data_to_csv() to return a string of your new data record instead of a one row dataframe.

Another way would be to open 'AVG_DATA.csv' with pandas, concat/append the output of avg_data_to_csv(), and then save it as 'AVG_DATA.csv'.